# Printf not able to use input obtained using bash read command

Tags: bash, sh

I am making this BASH script to "automatically" setup a game-server (minecraft), although it has nothing to do with my question.
The real question is:
I am reading different values from the user using the read function, and in every other part of the code is working correctly, but when I'm trying to make a file that contains user input it disappears:

```
read -p "Value:   " id
printf "java -Xms512M -Xmx$idM -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=100 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90 -XX:G1NewSizePercent=50 -XX:G1MaxNewSizePercent=80 -XX:G1MixedGCLiveThresholdPercent=35 -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -Dusing.aikars.flags=mcflags.emc.gs -jar spigot-$version.jar" >start.sh
```

The thing is that the id should be replaced with whatever INT value , but instead the M gets replaced as well.

Let's make an example so you understand better:
i input 2500
but when i open start.sh that part looks like this: -Xmx
the M disappeared and INT didn't get replaced.

Any fix? Thank you.

Comment: `$idM` is looking for a variavble named `idM`.  Try `${id}M`

Comment: @William is absolutely right.  It is good practice to ALWAYS delimit variable names with `{` and `}` to avoid this kind of parsing error.

Comment: In general, avoid parameter expansion in the first argument to `printf`. Make it a static string with placeholders to be replaced by your parameter values.

Comment: I don't understand why people are marking this question for closure. bash programming is perfectly on topic for this site.

Comment: @einpoklum As the rationale puts it, "While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers". It's unlikely that people having problems using `printf` with `read` input will benefit from this solution. (If it had been narrowed down to "how do I put letters immediately after a variable expansion in a string", it would have been different)

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a variable name `idM`?  Intead of:

```
printf "java -Xms512M -Xmx$idM -XX ...
```

you probably meant

```
printf "java -Xms512M -Xmx${id}M -XX
```

but in this case, you likely want:

```
printf "java -Xms512M -Xmx%dM -XX ..." "$id"
```

but it seems really strange to use a variable named "id" to indicate the maximum size of the memory allocation pool.  I would recommend using a better name.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, the 'M' is not part of any variable because it's indicating the amount of MEGABYTES allocating for Java runtime XMX and XMS (maximum and minimum).
I managed to fix by using quotes inside quotes: ```printf "java -Xms'$id'M```

Comment: Quotes is not the correct way to separate the 'M' from the variable name.  You really ought to use `${id}M`